# My Euclid Algorithm is working very slowly

Tags: java, algorithm

This code compiles fine, but when I run it, it asks for my two numbers as expected and then just sits there and doesn't do anything at all.  I've searched the Internet and worked on this all day.  I'm finally caving and asking for help.

Is the issue that it's not looping back up automatically?  After 10 hours at this, I've found nothing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EA
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // get first integer from user
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the larger integer: ");
        int I;
        I = input.nextInt();

        // get second integer from user
        System.out.println("Please enter the smaller integer: ");
        int J;
        J = input.nextInt();

        //resolve the issue of zero
        while(J<1)
        {
            System.out.println("Can not divide by zero!");
            System.out.println("Please enter new smaller integer: ");
            J = input.nextInt();

            //do the calculations
            while(J>0)
            {
                int Remainder;
                Remainder = I % J;

                while(Remainder>0)
                {
                    I = J;
                    J = Remainder;

                    return;

                }
                System.out.println("GCD is" + J);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not doing anything rather than looping infinitely? Try adding output to all the loops or debugging the code by stepping through it one line at a time.

Comment: My best analysis so far: The "ask J twice" is causing the code to get frozen. When that is solved, the `return` will break the logic. And when the `return` issue is solved, the infinite loop will kick in. And that is only counting the major issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than 1 error: the return in the while, the algorithm and the brackets of the first while.

1) When you resolve the issue of zero, the brackets of the while must be closed suddenly after you re-assign the value of the variable J.

```
while (J < 1) {
    System.out.println("Can not divide by zero!");
    System.out.println("Please enter new smaller integer: ");
    J = input.nextInt();
}
```

2) The algorithm for computing the gcd is the following:

```
function gcd(a, b)
    while b ≠ 0
       t := b
       b := a mod t
       a := t
    return a
```

Here is the correct version of your code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // get first integer from user
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the larger integer: ");
    int I;
    I = input.nextInt();

    // get second integer from user
    System.out.println("Please enter the smaller integer: ");
    int J;
    J = input.nextInt();

    // resolve the issue of zero
    while (J < 1) {
        System.out.println("Can not divide by zero!");
        System.out.println("Please enter new smaller integer: ");
        J = input.nextInt();
    }
    // do the calculations
    while (J != 0) {
        int Remainder;
        Remainder = I % J;
        I = J;
        J = Remainder;
    }
    System.out.println("GCD is" + I);

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Huge help to see how it should be laid out.  Now I know how to make it work I can try and add more abilities to it and continue my learning.  Thank you again!

Comment: I'm happy to see that my answer has helped you!

Answer (score 2):

SJuan mention that the return breaks the loop, which is true, but even if it's fixed there are a few other issues:

- The inner while never end (infinite loop)
- The result will be stored in `J` - not in `I`
- `System.out.println("GCD is " + I);` Should be printed outside of the outer while!

The "heart" of your program should do this:

```
    // we get here with valid values stored in I,J
    int Remainder  = I % J;
    //do the calculations
    while(Remainder>0)
    {
        I = J;
        J = Remainder;
        Remainder  = I % J;
    }
    System.out.println("GCD is " + J);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I was seriously messing up the place of the while comments.  Apparently the } symbols have to close in a certain order.  Who knew? :)

Answer (score 2):

Among other things already mentioned, you are confusing `while` with `if`.  You have put your algorithm logic inside a `while` loop that only runs if the first input is bad.

```
// get first integer from user
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the larger integer: ");
int I;
I = input.nextInt();

// get second integer from user
System.out.println("Please enter the smaller integer: ");
int J;
J = input.nextInt();

//resolve the issue of zero
while(J<1)
{
    // You never reach here under ordinary conditions
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  First day on the job. :p

Comment: Job? Surely you have not been hired as a programmer.  This looks more like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` in the middle of the loop will end the execution.

This one

```
 while(Remainder>0)
 {
     I = J;
     J = Remainder;

    return; <------- THIS IS THE RETURN THAT BREAKS ALL

 }
```

so it does not get to the `System.out.println`.

UPDATE: Also, you do `input.nextInt()` twice for `J`. Probably from your description, it keeps waiting for you for entering the third integer.

Comment: Yes, but if you take out the `return`, you have an infinite loop because the inner loop never modifies `Remainder`.  The inner loop shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: @paddy yes, didn't catch that, thanks. This code is a bug festival.

Comment: Thank you!  Honestly, I'm not even sure why I put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

Well Euclid's algorithm has a drawback as both the inputs should be non zero to compute         the Greatest common divisor . But if you want to find out the GCD when one of the input is a zero ('0') tweak the logic a bit . When one of the input is zero the GCD is 1, and 'a' should be greater than 'b' to compute GCD. Check the snippet below:

```
    if (a < b) {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    if (b == 0) {
        System.out.println("1");
    } else {
        while (b != 0) {
            r = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = r;
        }
```